# how to edit table values single row at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my table am gettting is as follows

```
<tbody>
<?php foreach($result as $r): ?>
$id=<?php echo $r->content_id; ?>;
<tr id="<?php echo $r->content_id; ?>" class="editable"  >
<td><?php echo $r->content_s_no; ?>  </td>
<td><?php echo $r->content; ?>  </td>
<td><input type="button" value="edit" id='$id' class="edit"/>
<input type="button" value="save" class="save"/>
</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

and the script am using is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".edit").click(function()
{
var ID=$(this).attr('content_id');
alert (ID);
tinymce.init({
    selector: "tr.editable",
    inline: true,
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
 $(".save").show();
    $(".edit").hide();
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".save").hide();
    $(".edit").show();

});
</script>
```

my issue is when am clicking edit button in one row the edit buttons in all the rows is hiding and showing save button. i need to hide only that particular row edit which am clicking. what is the wrong step am doing in my code. please someone help me thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one.

change this two lines

```
<input type="button" value="edit" id='$id' class="edit"/>
<input type="button" value="save" class="save"/>
```

with

```
<input type="button" value="edit" id='edit_<?php echo $r->content_id; ?>' class="edit"/>
<input type="button" value="save" class="save" id="save_<?php echo $r->content_id; ?>"/>
```

now change your javascript function like

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".edit").click(function()
        {
            var ID=$(this).attr('content_id');
            alert (ID);
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "tr.editable",
            inline: true,
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft    aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
    });
     $("#save_"+ID).show();    //changed line
     $("#edit_"+ID).hide();    //changed line
    });
});
```

please let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: same issue. clicking edit button on one row it is showing edit button and also save button in all the rows.

Comment: yes this code means,if you click on a particular edit button only that edit button will hide and other will be displayed.

Comment: please let me know what you want now?

Comment: hai aritra what you said is the one i require. but now what am facing is edit button is not hiding after it is clicked. and one more thing is when clicking one edit button that particular one has to hide and have to show save button but for me every hide and also every save button are displaying.